# how to publish .net core 3.1 application in window server 2008

Tags: iis

I have a DotnetCore 3.1 based website which I have to publish on the Windows 2008 server standard with the IIS 7.0 configuration.

how can I publish the DotnetCore based website in IIS 7.0? Do I need to upgrade my IIS from 7.0 to another? I have already installed a 3.1 hosting bundle. OS is x64 based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run (at least) web-facing services on supported OS versions or you risk making your security issues our collective problem.

As it happens .net Core 3.1 requires at least Windows Server 2012 R2. (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore31)

Comment: should I drop the idea of publishing?

Comment: Using a framework that can't be installed on the operating system in question, which in turn is no longer supported? Definitely. But if you can get a machine (or VM, or hosted Windows server) running a current Windows version, by all means, go right ahead.